# Bug after restarting gnome shell

Tags: gnome, workspaces, activities-overview

Whenever I restart the gnome shell and go to activities overview, instead of normally seeing all windows of one workspaces, I see all windows of all workspaces jumbled together. Also, all the preview of windows in the right side is gone. The bug goes away if I again go to activities overview though.I think this is a bug in gnome-shell, please let me know if you have the same problem. Here is the screenshot.

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Steps to Reproduce the bug:

- Restart gnome shell by pressing `Alt+F2`.
- Go to Activities Overview by pressing `Super`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to disable all extensions and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Yep. The issue still exists. Can you try to reproduce the bug? It goes away after you go to overview again

Comment: I tried to, but I am not able to reproduce it. I think you should report it to Launchpad. You can read [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) about how to report a bug.

Comment: Oh. That's weird, I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 multiple times and faced this bug every single time. I'll report it

Comment: I seem to be able to reproduce this bug now, although I am not sure what has changed in the meantime. In my case the windows come back to normal only after clicking on them. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: The same thing happened for me. I'm sorry. I couldn't file a bug report.